# How to create the tabs dynamically in VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, tab

I have a requirement to display the custom object records as a Dynamic Tab in a VF Page. I am able to create the static Tabs but I am not able to create the Tabs dynamically based on the Custom Object Records.
For example, I have a custom object called Product Initiative. In the Product Initiative object we have 4 records like product1, Product2...and Product4. In the VF page I need to display this 4 records as a Tab. If the user creates one more record in Product Initiative then the 5th Tab has to be added dynamically. Hope the requirement is clear to all. Please find below the image for more clarification. 
Can anyone please help me out in the requirement?    [image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery tabs for this.
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

You can collect all the records in a list by SOQL query and then using repeat tag you can use jquery tabs to display then as tabs.

Comment: thanks for your reply i already tried this method but i can't display a tab format.

Comment: I used this as well to get around lack of support for `apex:repeat`. Always amazing some of the stuff they make a pain to work with.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this awesome package which uses jquery behind the scene -

http://blogforce9.blogspot.com/2013/05/easy-jquery-tabs-for-visualforce-pages.html

Demo Link - http://blogforce9dev-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/jQueryTabDemo

Answer (score 0):

This was solved in a discussion on the developer forum. This is the current link -
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000094jfIAA - read all the way to the bottom for the full solution.